# AngularJS latest version of CDN not working

Tags: angularjs

I know this could be a silly mistake from my end on `AngularJS`, but I'd like to understand why `CDN` version `1.5.8` (`https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js`) of angularjs not working, while when I tested with `CDN` version `1.2.29` (`https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.29/angular.min.js`) works very fine. What I need to change in the code?

**firstHtml.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.29/angular.min.js"></script> -->
</head>
<body>
    <input ng-model="name"> Hello From {{name}}
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: When I try the 1.5.8 link directly in the browser it shows the code - how do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: the same code works with CDN 1.2.29, not with 1.5.8, what I need to change in the code in order to make it working. I'm using eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

It's not issue with the angular reference,

You have not mentioned the ng-app name

```
<html ng-app="whateveryourmodule">
```

Working [`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/AaE07X7mUbU3vmCvN8WD?p=preview)

Comment: I simply paste your demo code by making new html file in eclipse, still dont get worked. What wrong here in my eclipse?

Comment: run the app and check the console

Comment: @javatechnology what happened?

Comment: looks like issue in the browser of eclipse, in chrome working fine

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to AngularJS and You come to this page. I think the reason it's not working is add **ng-app** to the body tag of HTML and not on HTML tag.

Example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Getting started with angular</title>
  <!-- angular cdn -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="">

  <label>Name: </label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="name"> Welcome Mr. {{name}}

  <!-- angular module file -->
  <script type="text" src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[https://plnkr.co/edit/PUFDtSrK6q2zbL12ccoR?p=preview][Plunker]

Answer (score -2):

Do you want to try this code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="appName">
<head>
  <title>Hello, Angular</title>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-init="name='World'">
  <label>Name</label>
  <input ng-model="name" />
  <span>Hello, {{ name }}!</span>
  <p ng-bind="name"></p>
</body>
</html>
```